# RSpec without rails not loading files in spec/support

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

In the file spec/support/factory_girl.rb I have

```
fail "At least this file is being required"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

and I have in some spec code

```
require 'pmc_article'
require 'pmc_article_parser'
require 'factory_girl'
require_relative './factories/pmc_article_factory'

RSpec.describe PMCArticle do
  let(:pmc_article) do
    build(:pmc_article)
  end

  it 'parses pmid' do
    expect(pmc_article.article_id_pmid).to eq '123456'
  end
end
```

but when I run `bundle exec rspec` I get

```
  1) PMCArticle parses pmid
     Failure/Error: build(:pmc_article)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `build' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PMCArticle:0x007feac3cc5078>
     # ./spec/pmc_article_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/pmc_article_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I assume that rspec is failing to require `spec/support/factory_girl.rb`, even though the [factory girl getting started guide](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) says I should put the file there.

I had run the command line command to initialize rspec when I started the project, which was before I was using factory girl for the project.

Why isn't RSpec loading files in spec/support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing magic about spec/support. If you use rspec-rails then it used to add a line loading everything in there automatically but  as of of 3.1.0 it doesn't - see this [commit](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/commit/defb19a4db9e817dbdb068f8e0b4db552ffef061)).

I can only assume that the factory girl docs assume the presence of this now deactivated feature. You can turn this on for your project by adding

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

To your spec helper or of course you could move that `config.include` line into your main spec_helper file.

In a non rails world, replace `Rails.root` with wherever the root of your project is.

Comment: I don't understand. If the question says "RSpec without Rails", isn't tagged with Rails, but the answer uses `Rails.root`, (´・_・`)...

Answer (score 1):

Though the FactoryGirl guide suggests configuring RSpec in support/factory_girl.rb, you still need to require that file manually. I recommend adding the following to your spec_helper:

```
require 'factory_girl' # require the gem
require_relative './support/factory_girl' # this should point to the factory_girl.rb file.
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem now and @Frederick Cheung's solution didin't work.  Maybe I'm not sure where I should insert this line: `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`.  So I tried @Guacamolay's idea. It is simple too and pretty worked fine.