# Cannot load session_helpers from RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

When I run RSpec tests I get:

```
/home/jasiekm/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- ../../spec/support/features/session_helpers (LoadError)
```

My repo is just cloned from [here](https://github.com/netguru-training/katowice-ror-workshops-2015).

I want to add manual `require` because I have problem similar to [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1165).

What is the problem with my `require`?

My `features.rb` file:

```
require '../../spec/support/features/session_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

I just want to include this specific `session_helpers.rb` file and that's all.

EDIT: but when I paste code from `session_helpers.rb` manually everything works. But I suppose it isn't elegant way.

Comment: I think your path is wrong. `features.rb` is in the `spec/support` directory.  So you may `require_relative 'features/session_helpers'`

Answer (score 1):

It's relative to `rspec`, most likely (the current working directory).

Check out the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29443776):

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Actually this line is present in repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just add this line to `spec_helper.rb` file (not `features.rb`):

```
require 'support/features/session_helpers'
```

Comment: That's what the linked solution above is doing (albeit in a way that supports multiple files).